# Failing to force Python 2.7.4 to run in 32-bit mode on OS X 10.8.3

Tags: eclipse, macos, python-2.7, pydev, 32-bit

I have been trying to force Python 2.7.4 to run in 32-bit mode on OS X 10.8.3 by default. I can get Python to run in 32-bit mode by running python32. But when I try to configure Eclipse+PyDev to run Python, it ends up running in 64-bit mode.
I have also tried

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

and

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

but neither seem to have any effect on my Python, and it still runs in 64-bit.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to permanently run Python 2.7 in 32-bit mode. Alternately, I am open to any solution that makes Eclipse/PyDev use the 32-bit Python.

My Python has been installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` and sys.executable returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` on my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made python go to 32-bit:

```
arch -i386 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

import ctypes
print ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)

output -> 4
```

but I had the same issue as you that couldn't setup a permanent solution with environment flags as before.